# Tridion 2013SP1 and Visual studio 2015

Tags: 2013-sp1

I am creating a development machine for a client with Tridion 2013SP1. Everything was working fine, up until I installed Visual Studio 2015. After a restart, I was unable to load the Tridion website and I got this error message.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ajaxmin, Version=3.30.3576.28515, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b60b318a12299464' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

Could not load file or assembly 'ajaxmin' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings 
    Request path: /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 13 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

It looks like is cannot load dll's that are located in the web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin folder. When I add this particular dll in the GAC, it can find it but then it just gives the same error message for another DLL.

Visual Studio installed newer versions of the .NET framework, so I guess it is related to that, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I already tried repairing the Tridion installation, but no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you installed new VS which would have installed new .NET framwework, I would suggest clearing the temp folder under ASP.NET framework folder. It will be in `%TEMP%Temporary ASP.NET Files` or `%WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

You might need to clear all the temporary ASP.NET Files under all the framework folders

Comment: Thanks! This did it. I had already removed all higher versions of .NET but it was still giving errors. Solved after removing %WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 2):

Following in a [link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-D5F5900D-D4EB-4ABD-B2D7-8CDD8866D76A) to the supported versions for .NET for Tridion 2013 SP1.

If you have an unsupported version of .NET, you can uninstall in from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Feature".

Also make sure that your tridion web-app application pool is running with the right version of .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended to install un-supported .net versions on your CMS machine. if you get any Audit from SDL this would be first thing to be asked to remove.

also you could face unexpected issues and getting Tridion support on unsupported version would be difficult.